# SQL: Return rows where datetime of entry is most recent to specified time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

First post - apologies for that long winded question. Using SQLServer2012

This will better illustrate my need:

I have an activity log of agents - each time they change their phone status in our call center. Each user can have a few or hundreds a day. I need to input a datetime and have it return the status that each one had PREVIOUS to that datetime.

Currently, this is my issue. This code gives me what Im asking for but minus one piece of information I need:

```
SELECT        
MAX(StatusDateTime),
UserId

FROM            
AgentActivityLog 
WHERE
StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2/9/2016 00:00:00' AND '2/9/2016 08:52:12'

GROUP BY 
UserId

order by 2,1
```

That returns a list of userid's where I get the most recent entry before 2/9/2016 08:52:12.

```
2016-02-09 08:02:21.000 AbalosB
2016-02-09 08:06:12.000 AnkenbrD
2016-02-09 07:48:58.000 AzziV
2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 BachmayM
```

My problem is that I also need to include one other column that contains the name of the status they were in. When I do this, it includes every unique time in that range; I assume because now it selecting the max time for each status - not the max time only.

Example of what it returns when I add StatusKey to Select and Group By:

```
2016-02-09 08:01:43.000 AbalosB     Gone Home
2016-02-09 08:02:21.000 AbalosB     Available
2016-02-09 08:00:50.000 AnkenbrD    Gone Home
2016-02-09 08:04:40.000 AnkenbrD    On ACD Call
2016-02-09 08:06:02.000 AnkenbrD    ACW - After Call Work
2016-02-09 08:06:12.000 AnkenbrD    Available
```

I need to include that Status column but I only need the entry that came first before the time I input. I used a range this time, I could just enter in '2/9/2016 08:52:12' and Id need the entry that

Comment: Woah, so many responses so quickly. Let me give these a try, I REALLY appreciate the responses. This will save me hours of tedious manual work...

Answer (score 0):

If you need just one record, the most recent one, then you can use `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 StatusDateTime, UserId, StatusKey
FROM AgentActivityLog 
WHERE StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2/9/2016 00:00:00' AND '2/9/2016 08:52:12'
ORDER BY StatusDateTime DESC
```

**Edit:**

To get the most recent record *per user* use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT StatusDateTime, UserId, StatusKey
FROM (
  SELECT StatusDateTime, UserId, StatusKey, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId 
                            ORDER BY StatusDateTime DESC) AS rn
  FROM AgentActivityLog 
  WHERE StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2/9/2016 00:00:00' AND '2/9/2016 08:52:12') t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Beautiful - that works infinitely faster and much cleaner than anything I had before. Many thanks. Literally - hours of work saved.

Comment: @Anthony Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176102.aspx) and a CTE

```
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
        StartDateTime,
        UserId,
        StatusKey,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY StartDateTime DESC) r
    FROM AgentActivityLog
    WHERE StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2/9/2016 00:00:00' AND '2/9/2016 08:52:12'

)
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE r = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Window function for this, assuming that you're using a version of SQL Server from the past decade. You'll need to enclose it in a CTE since Window functions are only available in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        UserId
        StartDateTime,
        StatusKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY StartDateTime) AS row_num
    FROM
        dbo.AgentActivityLog
    WHERE
        StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2/9/2016 00:00:00' AND '2/9/2016 08:52:12'
)
SELECT
    UserId,
    StartDateTime,
    StatusKey
FROM
    MyCTE
WHERE
    row_num = 1
```

Alternatively, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT
    L.UserId,
    L.StartDateTime,
    L.StatusKey
FROM
    dbo.AgentActivityLog L
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT UserId, MAX(StartDateTime) AS MaxStartDateTime
        FROM dbo.AgentActivityLog
        WHERE StatusDateTime BETWEEN '2/9/2016 00:00:00' AND '2/9/2016 08:52:12'
        GROUP BY UserId
    ) SQ ON
        SQ.MaxStartDateTime = L.StartDateTime AND
        SQ.UserId = L.UserId
```

Both approaches assume that you will not have exact duplicates for the `StartDateTime` values for a given `UserId`.

Also, you should avoid using `ORDER BY 2, 1` (or any column numbers) and use the actual columns/expressions. Using the ordinal values is a bad habit that can often cause bugs and/or maintenance issues with code.